# Implementing a find system for a ListView in C#

Tags: c#, listview, search

I am creating an application in C# using a ListView control that lets you create lists. I am implementing a Find function using the `Find()` method. Here’s my code:

```
if (findTextBox.Text != "")
{
    ListViewItem[] lviFoundList = listItemsList.Items.Find(findTextBox.Text, true);
    amountFound.Text = "Found " + Convert.ToString(lviFoundList.Count());
    if (lviFoundList.Count() != 0)
    {
        int firstItemIndex = lviFoundList[0].Index;
        listItemsList.Items[firstItemIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
else
{
    amountFound.Text = "Found 0";
}
```

However, it doesn’t return any matches. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What text are you searching by, and what values for the [`.Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `ListViewItem` do you have? Also, have you debugged and checked which branch you're entering (from what I see above, you can't tell if you're entering the empty string branch, or the text entered but no search results branch) that you don't have a bug looking at the wrong `findTextBox` input where it's always evaluating as empty and thus never searching?

Comment: Yes, you are searchig for the Items Key, not the actual text. See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method requires your listView item's ***Name***, did you set your list view item's [name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? If you want to search for text you can use this:

```
var lviFoundList = new List<ListViewItem>();
foreach(var item in listItemsList.Items)
{
   if(item.Text == findTextBox.Text) lviFoundList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Find() Method looks at the `ListViewItem`'s name, not it's text.

You want this instead:

```
if (findTextBox.Text != "")
{
    List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItems>();
    foreach ListViewItem lvi in listItemsList.Items
    {
         if (lvi.Text == findTextBox.Text)
            items.Add(lvi);
    }

    amountFound.Text = "Found " + Convert.ToString(lviFoundList.Count());

    if(lviFoundList.Count() != 0)
    {
        int firstItemIndex = lviFoundList[0].Index;
        listItemsList.Items[firstItemIndex].Selected = true;
    }



}
else
{
    amountFound.Text = "Found 0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the `ListView.Find()` method is rather poor and it's much easier to roll your own with LINQ. Think about what `Find` really is trying to accomplish -- a specific filtering, typically one record.

The first step, if you haven't already, would be to keep a cached collection of your data objects. Let's assume you have a list of `Person` classes like so:

```
class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string JobTitle { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `MainForm` you have a `ListView` and a member variable `people` defined as a `List<Person>`. Your `ListView.Items` should reflect the contents of this `List<Person>`.

So now maybe you want to find a person based on their `FirstName` or `LastName`, right? You could use LINQ in a function like so:

```
int FindFirstIndexOfPersonNamed(string firstOrLastName)
{
  // WARNING: This is case sensitive!
  return people.FindIndex(p => p.FirstName.Contains(firstOrLastName) || p.LastName.Contains(firstOrLastName));
}
```

Since your `ListView.Items` should be reflecting your `List<Person>` the `index` should be identical:

```
// Get the found item and do whatever you want with it...
var selectedListViewItem = listView.Items[index];
```